# Dynamically generate components based on array of objects

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Alright, I’m pretty new to Ember (and frameworks alike) so forgive me if I’m missing something obvious.

I have a settings menu component which contains some logic. A piece of that logic is a computed property that returns an array of objects (possible settings). It passes that data down to a view component.

**menu-component.js**

```
possibleSettings: computed(function() {
    // Example of returned data
    return [
        {
            type: 'time',
            min: 1,
            max: 60,
        },
        },
            type: 'sound',
            values: [‘alarm’, ‘beep’, ‘rooster’],
        },
    ]
});
```

**menu-component.hbs**

```
{{menu-component/menu-view
    possibleSettings=possibleSettings}}
```

Each setting has it's own component, for example:

**menu-component/time.hbs**

```
<label>Time</label>
{{input value=time}}
```

**menu-component/sound.hbs**

```
<label>Sound</label>
{{dropdown items=sounds}}
```

I want the view component to render these components, based on the result of possibleSettings. So following the example data above, it needs to render both the Time and Sound component.

I guess I need something like this but I can’t wrap my head around the last bit. I could use a fresh look at things.

**menu-component/settings-view.hbs**

```
<div>
    {{#each possibleSettings as |setting|}}
        {{#if (eq setting.type time)}}
            {{component ‘menu-component/time'}}
        {{else if (eq setting.type sound)}}
            {{component ‘menu-component/sound'}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is that you are not wrapping `time` in quotes in your handlebars, so it is looking for a property named `time` on the component itself, instead of the string `"time"`. Also, I don't think you need to use the component helper here, since you are hardcoding the component name in anyways. Here is your hbs edited in this regard

```
<div>
  {{#each possibleSettings as |setting|}}
    {{#if (eq setting.type "time")}}
      {{menu-component/time}}
    {{else if (eq setting.type "sound")}}
      {{menu-component/sound}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
{{#each possibleSettings as |setting|}}
  {{component (concat 'menu-component/' setting.type)}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about concat, that's the solution I was trying to realise. At the same time I had a typo in my computed property name which is why I spent two hours trying to figuring out why I couldn't access the object.keys.... d'oh! Cheers.